# How can I cut this string?

Tags: java, string

I have the following string.

```
#0
lock;
faceplayer;
say Hello Player!;
end;
#1
lock;
say I don't want to talk to you.;
end;
```

I would like to pass an int and have method return a string starting at #int that was passed until end;
How can this be done?

Comment: There is an easier way to word this.  What part of this string do you want to pass into the method?  What have you tried?

Comment: Not in a way that helps me figure out what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take that string and split on the '#' then you'll get an array

ex:

```
String[] split = yourString.split("#");
```

results in:

*0
lock;
faceplayer;
say Hello Player!;
end;*

*1
lock;
say I don't want to talk to you.;
end;*

append your # back to the beginning of it and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#0.to_s
lock;
faceplayer;
say Hello Player!;  
end;
#1.to_s
lock;
say I don't want to talk to you.;
end;
```

Or

```
"#0";
lock;
faceplayer;
say Hello Player!;
end;
"#1";
lock;
say I don't want to talk to you.;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. Made it fairly parametrized for flexibility.

```
public static String parse(int from, int to, String str) {
  if(str.indexOf("#" + Integer.toString(to)) > 0) {
      return str.substring(str.indexOf("#" + Integer.toString(from)), str.indexOf("#" + Integer.toString(to)));  
  } else {
      return str.substring(str.indexOf("#" + Integer.toString(from)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your text into a String I would put into a file. This way you don't have to recompile your code every time you change your text. I know this is not the exact solution you may have considered/explained above but it is a solution which may address your requirement/need here. Hope this helps you.

```
public class YourClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tagId = 1;
        System.out.println(searchPrint(tagId));
    }

    private static StringBuilder searchPrint(int tagId) {
        String tag = Integer.toString(tagId);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/one.txt"));
            try {
                String line = br.readLine();
                boolean display = false;
                // loop through to read each line in the file
                while (line != null) {
                    // set the flag to true so then we can print as soon as you
                    // find it
                    if (line.contains("#" + tag)) {
                        display = true;
                    }
                    // set the flag to false to stop print as soon as the end
                    // tag is found
                    else if (line.contains("end;")) {
                        display = false;
                    }

                    if (display == true) {
                        result.append(line);
                        //System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```